# разные TITLE и метатеги с помощью SSI

Tags: ssi

Перерабатываю сайт с использованием ssi включений (include virtual="..."). Всё, что касается body, сделала. Остался вопрос по поводу head.

**Хочу вставить тайтл и дескрипшн всех html-страниц в один файл для удобства редактирования.**

Но не нашла никакого толкового мануала на эту тему. Подскажите, как это делается. С указанием в head title, descriprion в виде переменных я, надеюсь, разберусь. **Но не понимаю даже приблизительно, как отображать значение этой переменной в зависимости от url?** Для этого потребуется создавать какой-то отдельный файл, видимо, где будут сопоставлены url и его title и description?

**Допустим, для страницы index.shtml значение переменной tit равно "Главная страница". а для страницы contacts.shtml та же tit имеет значение: "Связаться с нами".** И таких страниц - около 100.

Толкового руководства конкретно по моему вопросу не нашла. Может, неправильно вопрос формулирую?
За ссылку на хороший урок по этой теме тоже буду очень благодарна.

P.S. перепробовала и ssi и php, который рекомендовали в ответе. Не получается ничего. Выводится в html только код, а не результат его работы.

P.P.S. Привожу требуемые сведения - htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(database|1komnkv|2komnkv|3komnkv|admir|vasileos|vyborgs|kalin|kirovs|krasnogv|krasnosel|mosk|nevsk|petrogr|prim|frunz|centr|obl|komn|area)\.html $1\.php
RewriteRule ^(avtovo|adm|akadem|balt|buhar|vasostr|vladimirs|volkov|vyb|gork|grazhd|devjat|elizar|zvezdn|pushk|kirovzav|komend|krestoos|kupchino|ladog|lenins)\.html metro\.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^(lesn|ligov|lomon|mezhd|moskov|mvorota|narvs|gostdv|novocher|obvod|obuh|ozerki|parkpob|parnas|petrog|pioners|plalnev|vosst|pl-len|pl-muzh|politeh|primor|proletar)\.html metro\.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^(bolsh|veter|prosv|rybats|sadov|sport|stderev|tehnolog|udel|dyben|frunzen|chrech|chern|chkalov|elektrosila)\.html metro\.php?page=$1
```

Что касается сервера у хостера вижу следующее: Используемое ПО

> Все наши сервера работают под управлением OS CentOS 7. В качестве
>   дополнительной настройки мы используем решение CloudLinux.
>
> Установленные версии PHP: 5.2 (CGI), 5.3 (CGI), 5.4
>   (Apache/CGI/FastCGI), 5.5 (CGI), 5.6 (CGI), 7.0 (CGI, FastCGI на
>   тарифах Bitrix), 7.1 (CGI) MySQL: MariaDB v10 Панель управления:
>   ISPManager 5 (сервера sN.hostiman.ru, vipN.hostiman.ru), cPanel
>   (сервера cpanelN.hostiman.ru) Дополнительное ПО: Roundcube, phpMyAdmin

И хтмл-код страницы:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Текст тайтл</title>
    <meta name="description" content="текст описания.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="ключевые через запятую">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-
scale=1.0, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="Tue, 08 Jan 2019 20:50:28 GMT">
    <meta name="yandex-verification" content="цифры и буквы">
    <meta name="revisit-after" content="10 days">
    <meta name="robots" content="all">
    <meta name="robots" content="noyaca">
    <meta name="robots" content="noodp">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Текст">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Текст">
    <meta property="og:type" content="article">
    <meta property="og:image" content="12801024l.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image" content="1920-2.jpg">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/files/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script> <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://site.ru/myiesafari-1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../1style1.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../media1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../3media2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../media3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
    <style type="text/css">
      
     
      <!--Тут немножко тестовых стилей, которые еще не вынесены в файлы.css -->
      
  
</style></head>
  <body itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage">
    <header>
      <div class="column-left" itemprop="headline">
        <h1 itemprop="name">текст заголовка</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="column-center">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="column-right image1" itemprop="image" title="...">
        
      </div>
    </header>
    <div id="main">
      <article title="..." itemprop="mainContentOfPage" class="content">
        <h2 itemprop="description">...</h2>
        <br>
        <!--#include virtual="menu-cont.txt" --> <br>
        <h3 style="display:inline">...</h3>
        <p style="display:inline ">...</p>
        <div class="slide"> <label for="slide1" id="dalee"> Читать далее /
            Свернуть </label><br>
          <br>
          <input id="slide1" type="checkbox">
          <p>Много букв, аж целый абзац</p>
          <p style="display:inline">тоже абзац </p>
          <h5 style="display:inline">...</h5>
          <p style="display:inline"> ...</p>
          <h5 style="display:inline"><a href="../database.html">...</a></h5>
          <p style="display:inline"> ................</p>
          <p>текст</p>
          <p><strong>текст</strong> текст<strong>текст</strong>. текст</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>текст</p>
          <p>текст</p>
          <p>текст</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <aside>
        <div class="accordion">
          <ul>
            <!--#include virtual="menu-aside.txt" -->
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="counters"><!--#include virtual="counters.txt" --></div>
      </aside>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <!--#include virtual="footer.txt" -->
      <!--#include virtual="telefoniya.txt" --> </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Какие веб-сервера используются? Приложите код, иначе все это выглядит слишком размыто. [это](https://ruhighload.com/index.php/2010/04/06/nginx-memcached-ssi-%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-partials/) и [это](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html) видели?

Comment: Какие веб-вервера - понятия не имею. Хостер на мой запрос ответил, что технология ssi поддерживается. С этим проблем не будет. А что, собственно непонятно? Я хочу, чтобы теги title и description в секции head заполнялись значениями переменных. Допустим, для страницы index.shtml значение переменной tit было равно "Главная страница". а для страницы contacts.shtml та же tit имела значение: "Связаться с нами". И таких страниц - около 100. Выяснила, что технология ssi позволяет это делать. Но не нашла подробностей.

Comment: По первой ссылке ничего по теме вопроса не увидела. К кэшированию, которое там рассматривается, мой вопрос никакого отношения не имеет. Смотрю сейчас второй источник

Comment: Неправа по поводу 1 ссылки. Там почерпнула команду <!-- #echo var="tit"--> Хотя это как раз не составляло проблемы. Я немного дополнила вопрос. Надеюсь, так будет понятнее

Comment: Я спрашивал про окружение, в котором вы работаете, чтобы понять, нужны ли конфиги для них, и на каком языке нужен пример. Похоже вы не знакомы вообще с программированием. Накидал пример на PHP, он рабочий. Если не заработает, жду веб-сервера, их конфиги, установленные языки

Comment: 1. Основной файл расширение `.html`? добавьте в `.htaccess` это: `AddHandler server-parsed .html` 2. `<!--#include virtual="menu-cont.txt" -->` - веб-сервер видит расширение TXT, и не будет выполнять код. Переименуйте в `.php`, если там есть код PHP.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо Вам!. Я сейчас другие скрипты довожу "до ума". Чуть позже вернусь к тайтлам и мета. Напишу, что получилось.

Comment: Total, запросила у хостера: На сервере работает связка Apache+Nginx
Server version: Apache/2.4.6()
nginx version: nginx/1.14.1 Так и не работает у меня подставление тайтл из файла.php.         <title><!--#include virtual="/title2.php" --></title>,
<title><?php include("title2.php"); ?></title>,
<title><?php echo $title ?></title>
Никак не добиться отображения заголовков для конкретных страниц из привязываемого файла title2.php
Получаю в хтмл либо пустой тег <title></title>, либо отображение приведенного выше кода. title2.php пробовала загрузить и в дир. скриптов, и в дир. html-страниц.

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой пример для `<title>`.

Минимальный шаблон сайта `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><!--#include virtual="/title.php" --></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Скрипт подстановки `title.php`:

```
<?php

$titleList = [
  '/' => "Главная",
  '/about' => "О компании",
  '/contacts' => "Контакты"
];

$title =& $titleList[$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']];

echo $title ?? "Тайтл для отсутствующего пункта";
```

Если страниц много, лучше подрубить базу данных, откуда брать тайтлы.

Comment: Спасибо большое! С php я пока "на Вы",это правда. Сейчас, вроде бы нашла решение именно с помощью SSI. Буду пробовать и Ваш и свой вариант. Мне на данный момент мозга не хватает со всеми своими БД разобраться: БД, где хранятся данные, публикуемые на сайте, + БД, где хранятся данные личных кабинетов пользователей. Еще и БД с тайтлами / описаниями. О-о-о!

Comment: @Наталья, использовать SSI в вашем случае - странная затея. Я бы начал со знакомства с PHP и его конструкциями типа `require` и `echo`. И никакого SSI. Почему? Потому что невозможно передать из одной включаемой области в другие какие-то данные. Вот будет у вас 2 блока: "Привет, Наталья" вверху, а внизу: "Наталья, для вас есть спец предложение" - имя "Наталья" придется получать два раза, две авторизации, двойная нагрузка на базу. Если же формирование страницы сделать "монолитно" на PHP - то один раз.

Comment: Насколько я поняла, в SSI БД не используется. Используются простые текстовые файлы с фрагментами html-кода, который подгружается в нужные места. Даже мой вопрос с тайтлами и описаниями (desctiprion) не предполагает никакой базы. Все заголовки и описания будут браться из одного файла.txt    Кроме того, пишут, что  ssi быстрее php на 20-25%.

Comment: @Наталья, SSI - это простейший механизм включения. Я его не видел ни в одном из проектов, с которыми работал. Только свои эксперименты. SSI очень ограничен, и используется для специфических задач. В SSI можно использовать не только HTML! Выше пример на PHP. А про скорость вообще забудьте, на вашем уровне вы в нее не упретесь

Comment: А мне и не требуется,чтобы было сложно и громоздко. Мне нужно решение моей задачи удобным для меня способом. SSI мне очень удобен. Про скорость можно и на перспективу подумать, дабы не переделывать в дальнейшем.. Мой уровень начинался с табличной верстки в программе FrontPage. Ничего, подросла. Даже с моим гуманитарным образованием.  А php я изучаю не спеша, да. Но для обозначенной в вопросе задачи ограниченной сферы применения ssi вполне хватит. Спасибо

Comment: Ничего у меня не получается ни Вашим способом, ни моим.Записала в массив /index, присвоила ему значение "Эксперимент". + Внесла в хтмл внутрь тега тайтл <--#include virtual="/title2.php" --> (и в папке с хтмл на сервере сохраняла, и в папке скриптов, и путь полностью прописывала). В итоге получаю вместо ожидаемого значения в теге title тот код, который я туда вставляю: <title><--#include virtual='/src/title2.php' --></title>

Comment: 1. Весь код - в студию, дополните свой вопрос 2. `В итоге получаю вместо ожидаемого значения в теге title тот код, который я туда вставляю` - вот поэтому я жду какие у вас веб-сервера, и с какими конфигами. Nginx? Apache? Также названия файлов, у Nginx если он есть, может стоять отдача статики, и без включенного SSI, до апача запрос может не доходить. Если Апач, то `.htaccess` в студию

Comment: `А мне и не требуется,чтобы было сложно и громоздко. Мне нужно решение моей задачи удобным для меня способом.`. Если вы собираетесь работать в фирме, про SSI вас никто не спросит на собеседовании, а про PHP - почти везде (ну кроме go, nodejs и других относительно новых тенденций)

Comment: Нет :) Я пишу скрипты для своего сайта. И не собираюсь зарабатывать программированием. Во всяком случае, пока таких намерений у меня нет. Код, htaccess и данные от хостинг-провайдера дописала в сам вопрос. Этого достаточно? Если что-то еще необходимо, я могу запросить у службы поддержки. SSI поддерживается, это я запрашивала раньше.

Answer (score 0):

У МЕНЯ НЕ РАБОТАЕТ, УВЫ

Нашла хороший, на мой взгляд, учебник: http://froland.ru/samodel/ssi0.html
Там есть разделы по переменным окружения (в моей задаче подходит DOCUMENT_URI) и условным операторам.

То есть решение будет примерно таким:

```
<!--#if expr="$DOCUMENT_URI=/\/mosk\//" -->  // если url страницы содержит mosk, то
```

выполняется код HTML или инструкция SSI. В данном случае:

```
<title>Снять квартиру в Московском районе<title>
```

Ну, и все остальные условия аналогично прописать:

```
<!--#if expr="$DOCUMENT_URI=/\/1kkv\//" -->  // если url страницы содержит 1kkv, то
<title>Однокомнатные квартиры<title>
```

А на страницах в head указывать (это пример, я свои данные не подставляла сюда):

```
<title>Web Club Repository. <!--#echo var="TITLE" --></title>
<meta name="description" content="WebClub. Кладовая. <!--#echo var="DESCRIPTION" --> ">
```

и т.д. и т.п. Все эти условия в одном файле указываются. 
Осталось только понять, как этот файл "привязать".

P.S. Привязывается очень просто: include file в нужном месте кода.